# Why can't I use flex box in this div to center it both horizontally and vertically?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, positioning

I am trying to build a completely centered slider with images in different sizes.
I used flexbox to center the div of the slider and now I have to center the images inside it. I tried to use flexbox in there as well but it didn't seem to work for me.

I uploaded it [here](http://beenee.bplaced.net/test/) so that you can see whats wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your container is too big. Your container should be as big as your images OR you should put `display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items: center;` on the container that contains the images.

Either way, your container can't have a width of 100% or the inside will never be aligned to the center...

Comment: I try to both vertically and horizontally center the entry of .slider on my website. I tried to achieve it using flexbox but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit your css style by adding this:

```
.slider img {
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
```

Comment: But I try to center the images within the slider both vertically and horizontally.